# SQLite subtract time difference between two tables if there is a match

Tags: sqlite, time, match

I need some help with a SQLite Query. I have two tables, a table called 'production' and a table called 'pause':

```
CREATE TABLE production (
    date TEXT,
    item TEXT,
    begin TEXT,
    end TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE pause (
    date TEXT,
    begin TEXT,
    end TEXT
);
```

For every item which is produced, an entry in the table production with the current date, the start time and the end time (two timestamps in the format HH:MM:SS) is created. So let's assume, the production table looks like:

```
+------------+-------------+------------+----------+
|    date    |    item     |    begin   |   end    |
+------------+-------------+------------+----------+
| 2013-07-31 |    Item 1   |  06:18:00  | 08:03:05 |
| 2013-08-01 |    Item 2   |  06:00:03  | 10:10:10 |
| 2013-08-01 |    Item 1   |  10:30:15  | 14:20:13 |
| 2013-08-01 |    Item 1   |  15:00:10  | 16:00:00 |
| 2013-08-02 |    Item 3   |  08:50:00  | 15:00:00 |
+------------+-------------+------------+----------+
```

The second table also contains a date and a start and an end time. So let's assume, the 'pause' table looks like:

```
+------------+------------+----------+
|    date    |    begin   |   end    |
+------------+------------+----------+
| 2013-08-01 |  08:00:00  | 08:30:00 |
| 2013-08-01 |  12:00:00  | 13:30:00 |
| 2013-08-02 |  10:00:00  | 10:30:00 |
| 2013-08-02 |  13:00:00  | 14:00:00 |
+------------+------------+----------+
```

Now I wanna get a table, which contains the time difference between the production begin and end time for every item. If there is a matching entry in the 'pause' table, the pause time should be subtracted.

So basically, the end result should look like:

```
+------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------+
|    date    |    Item    | time difference (in seconds), excluding pause   |
+------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| 2013-07-31 |   Item 1   |                     6305                        |
| 2013-08-01 |   Item 1   |                     12005                       |
| 2013-08-01 |   Item 2   |                     13207                       |
| 2013-08-02 |   Item 3   |                     16800                       |
+------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

I am not really sure, how I can accomplish it with SQLite. I know that it is possible to do this sort of calculation with Python, but in the end I think it would be better to let the database do the calculations. Maybe someone of you could give me a hint on how to solve this problem. I tried different queries, but I always ended up with different results than I expected.

Comment: What does "matching" mean? Can the start/end times be in a pause?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that. Theoretically, this shouldn't be possible. A little background: I have a machine, where usually people are working. During their lunch break, the machine continues to work on producing the item. (However, an item can only be started or finished with user input.) Now, I am interessted in how much time per day people have worked on each item. So I need to subtract the pause interval from the total working interval of the machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert a time string to the number of seconds, use the [strftime function](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) with the `%s` modifier.
(A time string without a date part will be assumed to have the date `2000-01-01`, but this cancels out when computing the differences.)

To compute the pause times for a specific `production` record, use a correlated subquery; the [total](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#sumunc) aggregate is needed to cope with zero/one/multiple matching pauses.

```
SELECT date,
       item,
       sum(strftime('%s', end) - strftime('%s', begin) -
           (SELECT total(strftime('%s', end) - strftime('%s', begin))
            FROM pause
            WHERE pause.date   = production.date
              AND pause.begin >= production.begin
              AND pause.end   <= production.end)
          ) AS seconds
FROM production
GROUP BY date,
         item
```

Comment: During breakfast, I got the idea to solve the problem with two subquerries and a join. It worked, but your solution is way better and faster. Thanks for the great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I found is:

```
SELECT
    cast(
        (
            strftime('%s',time_arrived)-strftime('%s',time_departed)
        ) AS real
   )/60/60 AS elapsed
FROM date AS t;
```

For aditional information check this [blog article](http://greladesign.com/blog/2011/01/09/sqlite-calculate-difference-between-datetime-fields/).