# Calculating time difference between two sqlite columns and showing the result on a Edittext

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have SQLite table named "Att_Table" with 5 columns:

- id
- name
- date
- timein
- timeout

I have inserted data in these columns through two different Activity (using insert and update). Now I want to calculate the time difference between `timeout` and `timein` column so that I can calculate the total working hours.

I also want to display that result in a EditText.

This method is in DatabaseHelper class:

```
  public Cursor workinghours() {
                final String TABLE_NAME = "attendance";
                SQLiteDatabase db  = this.getReadableDatabase();
                String selectQuery = "SELECT  total(strftime('%s', timeout) - strftime('%s', timein) FROM"  +TABLE_NAME+  "WHERE _id='2' ";
                Cursor cursor      = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
                return cursor;
 }
```

The emulator shows the error in query(syntax error). I am new in android programming and I couldn't find any tutorial on this topic on internet so I tried this my self with some pieces of codes.

This method is in activity:

```
 public  void working_hours() {

        Cursor result = mydb.workinghours();
        w_hours.setText(result.toString());

    }
```

w_hours is EditText where I want to show the total working hours.

I'm new here, sorry if I have done something stupid.

Comment: what you have tried ??

Comment: Show us the code

Comment: What is `total` in the query?

Comment: i saw this query on this site.i thought total is a built in function of sqlite.Here is the link from where i copied this::http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065846/sqlite-subtract-time-difference-between-two-tables-if-there-is-a-match

Answer (score 0):

SQLite stores `datetime` as `String`. That's why your code is not working because Strings can not be subtracted from each other.

You need to Parse the String time as Java `Time` object, then calculate the difference in Java instead of SQLite.

The following method can help. You need to save your Time Strings in 24 hours format for best result.

```
public static String getTimeDuration(String StartTime24, String EndTime24)
{
String duration = "";

    try 
    {
        SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        Date startTime = parseFormat.parse(StartTime24);
        Date endTime = parseFormat.parse(EndTime24);

        long mills = endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime();
        long minutes = mills/(1000 * 60);

        duration = "Difference is: " + minutes + " Minutes";
    }
    catch(ParseException ex)
    {
        // exception handling here
    }

    return duration;
}
```

Comment: but i have seen some queries where sqlite coloums can be subtracted.

Comment: Check this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065846/sqlite-subtract-time-difference-between-two-tables-if-there-is-a-match